# How to save the data in firebase parent key not defalut

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now i'm following android tutorial with firebase from youtube 
when i save the data the json data format the parent key is defaulted like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpLfl.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpLfl.png): [image]

I want to save the data not default key auto

I want to save the data format like this

[image]

When i save the data like this

```
//regi button
    mAdd_mypet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pets");

            String petid = reference.push().getKey();

            RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.genderGroup);
            RadioButton seletedRdo = (RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            final String selectedValue = seletedRdo.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put("petname", mPetName.getText().toString().trim());
            hashMap.put("petbreed", mPetBreed.getText().toString().trim());
            hashMap.put("petweight", mPetWeight.getText().toString());
            hashMap.put("birthday", mDisplayDate.getText().toString());
            hashMap.put("intro", mIntro.getText().toString());
            hashMap.put("gender", selectedValue);
            hashMap.put("petimage", myUrl);



            reference.child(petid).setValue(hashMap);

            startActivity(new Intent(MyPetRegActivity.this, MyPetListActivity.class));
            finish();


        }
    });
```

but the result save data parent key is auto

how can i do save the data clearly not make defualt not like 
'2okCgbdTqlVgk6oDqPi'

i want to make like this  -> 'firebase_01'

sorry my fool english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `String petid = reference.push().getKey();`

Change it for something like `String petid = 'firebase_01'`

When you do `reference.child(petid).setValue(hashMap);` the `child` method set the id, you can come with your own or ask firebase to generate one (which you are doing on your project), more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)